# Custom Web Template not displaying /default.aspx

Tags: web-template

I've made a custom web template based on BLANKINTERNET that has a specified DefaultPageLayout and a set of available page layouts, these are set in the Publishing Feature. I upload the solution and install it thru PowerShell and then I go to New site thru Site Actions. I can choose my template and a name for the new site but when I create it I just get a 404. I can however reach the settings of my newly created site thru Manage Content and Structure and there I see that the page layouts are there so that works. Does anyone have an idea why I get a 404? I have put a default.aspx file in the same folder as ONET.xml and Elements.xml but I have had no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u create a Module to provision the default.aspx page? This  element can not be in the ONET.xml so you'll have to create a Feature for this to provision the actual page.

U can read this post on how to implement Web Templates the right way. It is the best information available in my opinion:

[SharePoint 2010 and Web Templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx)

Comment: No, I haven't added a module, thx for the tip. Do you know of any other way to solve this without having to add a module?
What if I removed the default.aspx file all together?

Comment: For a site there needs to be a default.aspx. However with a WebTemplate you can create one without having an actual aspx file. Using a module like this:

<Module Name="MyDefaultPage" Url="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;" SetupPath="SiteTemplates\SPS">

Now a copy from the default.aspx that is stored in the SiteTemplates\SPS is being provisioned, and you don't need an aspx file in your solution.